# When using a classification api for a AzureML model, how do I get a response indicating the percentage chance of each class

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

When I query the endpoint that Azure provides, it just gives me the raw outcome. For instance, if the classifications were 'True' or 'False', the api would just return 'True' or 'False' instead of '23% True, 77% False', which is what I want.

Comment: I asked this on Reddit yesterday, but haven't received a response, so I thought I'd try me luck here. Hopefully a dev from microsoft will see this.

Comment: Can you edit the question and specify which classification endpoint are you working with? What information does it consume? Is it some model pretrained by Microsoft or did you train and deploy it with AzureML yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using an online endpoint, this is likely the solution, to replace 'method': 'predict': with 'method' : 'predict_proba' :, as in the comment in the code below.

```
from azureml.core import Webservice
import json

# if you called your service differently then change the name below
service = Webservice(ws, name="diabetes-service")

input_payload = json.dumps({
    'data': X_test[0:2].tolist(),
    'method': 'predict'  # If you have a classification model, you can get probabilities by changing this to 'predict_proba'.
})

output = service.run(input_payload)

print(output)
```

Taken from step 3 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/data-science-virtual-machine/how-to-track-experiments).